# Custom package installed but not found in another project

Tags: python, pycharm

I created a Python folder/project and published the code on Github. The folder has the following structure:

```
/modulename/__init__.py
/modulename/setup.py
/modulename/somefunctions.py
/modulename/README.md
```

The name of my package is `module_helloworld` and `setup.py` looks as follows:

```
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="module_helloworld",
    version="0.0.1",
    author="Hello World",
    author_email="hello@world.com",
    description="Hello world module",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://www.website.com",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

**In another project**, I installed it in Pycharm using the command

```
pip install git+https://github.com/Username/module-helloworld.git
```

That worked fine and in my Project Settings I see the package installed (*noticed that it was installed with the name `module-helloworld` however*) .

Now when I open the python console (or a new Python file) and I type

```
import module_helloworld
```

Then I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module_helloworld'
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case I had to restructure the folder structure as follows:

```
root/module_helloworld/__init__.py
root/module_helloworld/somefunctions.py
root/setup.py
```

And then in the other project I could call it in the normal way.

Inside the function `__init__.py` to import the functions I had to change it to the following:

```
# import somefunctions changed to:
from module_helloworld import somefunctions
```